# ng-repeat directives being pushed down by another directive

Tags: html, css, angularjs, less

So I'm pretty sure this a css issue (I'm using less), but I can't think of a better title. The problem is that one of my directives is being pushed up and is causing the other directives to be pushed down.

Here is a screenshot to show what I mean:

[Imgur Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRiyU.png)

I have these two directives inside of an ng-repeat. The second has an ng-if so it only displays after 7 "repeats". Here is my html from my index:

```
<div ng-repeat="acqui in acquis" class="repeated">
    <card-info class="card" acqui="acqui" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(img/company/' + acqui.seller.img + '.jpg)'}"></card-info>
    <ad-info class="ad-style" ng-if="!(($index + 1) % 7)"></ad-info>
</div>
```

My card-info directive works fine, but as soon as I throw in the ad-info directive, all of the cards on that line drop down a bit. Here is my html for the ad-info directive:

```
<div class="ads">
<div class="ad">
    <h4>Ad</h4>
    <h1>Company</h1>
    <img src="img/ad.png">
    <h2>Category</h2>
    <div class="lineup">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus rhoncus nunc ligula, eget vehicula neque pellentesque quis. Donec euismod est vel nulla auctor, nec tempus nulla fringilla.
        </p>
        <a href=""><h6 class="left"><u>More Info</u></h6></a>
        <a href=""><h6 class="right"><u>Advertise with Us</u></h6></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css (I am using less so it's formatted a bit differently):

```
.ad-style {
    .ads {
        .shadow;
        width: 350px;  
        height: 530px;
        display: inline-table;
        background-color: black;
        margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
        h1 {
            text-align: left;
            font-weight: 900;
            font-size: 50px;
            color: white;
            margin: 0 0 0 20px;
            padding-top: 8px;
            font-family: @Raleway;
        }
        img {
            margin-top: 50px;
            width: 300px;
        }
        h2 {
            font-family: @Open-Sans;
            font-weight: 600;
            color: white;
        }
        p {
            color: white;
            font-size: 15px;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 30px 0 30px;
            font-family: @Open-Sans;
            font-weight: 300;
        }
        h4 {
            float: right;
            color: white;
            font-weight: 300;
            margin: 15px 20px 0 0;
        }
        h6 {
            font-family: @Open-Sans;
            font-weight: 300;
            font-size: 10px;
            margin-top: 40px;
        }
        .left {
            float: left;
            margin-left: 20px;
            color: white;
        }
        .right {
            float: right;
            margin-right: 20px;
            color: white;
        }
    }
}
```

I'll explain a bit of my experimentation and what I think is happening.

If I remove the h4, h1, img, and h2 from the ad html it positions correctly, but only if I remove all 4. If I remove any combination the others (1, 2, or 3 of any of the elements) it still has the same issue. This tells me that it has something to do with the styling of those 4 elements.

Some of the things I've already tried:

I tried making .ad-style position relative and .ads position absolute. This fixed the height positioning issues, but made it so the ad-info directive was overlaid on top of next card-info directive. I'm perfectly fine with using this as a solution if anyone knows a way to fix that.

While that didn't work, I did find an actual solution. I moved the h1, h2, img, and h2 elements below the closing div of lineup class and then positioned all of the elements of the ad-info directive using transform translate. I really would prefer not to use this hack as it's just bad practice.

Other than the issue of the whole directive being pushed up, everything is positioned correctly inside of both directives. I really am at a loss and have no idea what to try next. This is pretty much the last thing I need to do to finish this project and I am dying to launch.

Any recommended solutions? I can post more of my css if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add fiddle?

Comment: It's really too big of a project to make a fiddle. I use a db and have a lot of other code making everything work right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I found a fix that is still a bit of a cheap hack, but I like it a lot more than what I had before.

I went ahead and added position relative to ad-style and position absolute to ads. This of course had the same issue of making the directive overlay on top of the next so I had to come up with a solution for that.

The best I could come up with was adding an empty div right after my ad-info directive so my html becomes:

```
<div ng-repeat="acqui in acquis" class="repeated">
    <card-info class="card" acqui="acqui" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(img/company/' + acqui.seller.img + '.jpg)'}"></card-info>
    <ad-info class="ad-style" ng-if="!(($index + 1) % 7)"></ad-info>
    <div class="ad-spacing" ng-if="!(($index + 1) % 7)"></div>
</div>
```

I then styled ad-spacing like so:

```
.ad-spacing {
    width: 350px;
    display: inline-table;
    margin: 0 10px -5px 10px;
}
```

This is just the same styling as my card-info directive so that it just gets pushed over. It's not perfect, but it gets the job done.